# Android ImageView handle Image orientation automatically

Tags: android, imageview, orientation

I'm trying to display an image in ImageView object in an Android app. Looks like the ImageView  doesn't handle image orientation automatically. (eg the Picture taken in Portrait mode gets displayed in Landscape mode).  Is there any property that can be set to handle the image orientation automatically.

I am able to solve this programmatically by reading the Exif orientation data and then calling the rotation method explicitly, which is available only in Os 11 and up so can't use this for 2.x Android system. Coming from iPhone programming background, I found this solution rather too complex (and expensive ??).

Any suggestion ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

what u need to do is override onConfigurationChanged(...,Config config) method and and refetch the drawable. u will have to put ur drawables in the relevant folders(drawable-hdpi,drawable-ldpi etc. Name will be same but sizes will be different). Android will get the correct drawable automatically.

I have just given u overview, Let me know if i need to explain it :)